# How to Expand and Hide Scrollviews with Button click in Android

Tags: android, button, hide, scrollview, expand

I'm trying to create a page with 4 buttons on top of each other.

When I click one button, the button should stay highlighted, a scrollview should appear below it with text and push the buttons below that button down (even off screen if necessary). Upon reclicking the button, the scrollview will hide again.

How do I get the scroll view to hide and reappear on a button click?

This is what i want it to look like: http://img407.imageshack.us/img407/3448/47163794.png

Comment: Sounds more like you should use an ExpandableListView.

Comment: Can you not use Visibility flag?

Comment: ExpandableListView may be more what I'm looking for, any good tutorials or samples for that? I'm having trouble finding them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what i have done recently with `ExpandableListView`. It is fairly easy.

It has one of the biggest constructors i have ever seen in android so far.

---

Create a layout with an `ExpandableListView`.

```
<LinearLayout>

    <ExpandableListView>
        <!-- Set the properties, if you need to see them, let me know. -->
    </ExpandableListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

Now use the layout in some view.

```
public void onCreate() {

    ExpandableListView example = findViewById(/* The id of the expandable list view */);


    example.setAdapter(
            new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
                        /* the context */,
                        /* the map of parents/groups */,
                        /* the layout to map the parents/groups to */,
                        /* the key to search for in the parents/groups map */,
                        /* the id of the textview inside the layout to map the parent/group to */,
                        /* the map of children */,
                        /* the layout to map the children to */,
                        /* the key to search for in the children map */,
                        /* the id of the textview inside the layout to map the children to */)
            )
}
```

---

There are other adapters available, but this is the most basic one.

Basically just take a look at the [developer website](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html). This [example](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/04/10/expandable-listview-in-android-using-simpleexpandablelistadapter-a-simple-example/) was also somewhat helpful, but the developer's website goes a long way.

If you have any questions let me know.

---

**FOLLOW UP**

> *he put createGroupList(). Looks like this was a function he commented
>   out. What is this doing exactly?*

He basically is creating the `List` of `HashMaps` in that function and returning the created object. Yes, you should do something like that, it helps keep your code a little cleaner.

> *Also, these lists show up really tiny, anyway to make them bigger?*

Modify the `TextView` you have displaying your children and groups. Add padding to their `View` in their `xml` layout. Just adjust the `dp`. And you can increase the `textSize` or you can add a `style` like i show below.

```
<TextView 
        android:id="@+id/groupTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
        android:paddingLeft="50dp"
        android:paddingTop="25dp"
        android:paddingBottom="25dp"/>
```

> *I want the parent group to be lists, but dont want the child group to
>   be sublists, I want them to be a text box I can add text to (which I
>   grab from the net). How do i make the children textboxes rather than
>   lists.*

You will probably need to create your own `Adapter` for that situation. You will need to extend the `BaseExpandableListAdapter`. I could be wrong, there may be an easier way... but i am not aware of one.

---

**ADDITIONAL FOLLOW UP**

> Not sure what you mean. The text getting entered in the child list
>   comes in at this line of code: child.put( "Sub Item", "test"). I can
>   put the text I want where it says "test" but "test" comes up under
>   every parent list.

Your `createChildList` needs to return a `List<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>`.

Your `createChildList` should look something like this:

```
private List<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> createChildList(int maxValue) {

                ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> groupList = 
                                new ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>();

                for (int i = 0; i <= maxValue; i++) {
                        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> childList = 
                                        new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                        for (int j = 0; j <= maxValue; j++) {
                                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                                map.put("Sub Item", "test: " + String.valueOf(j));
                                childList.add(map);
                        }

                        groupList.add(childList);
                }

                return groupList;
        }
```

Let me know if that works.

Comment: Hey this is really helpful thanks. A couple things, I followed the link to that example and its good, but for the /* the map of parents/groups */ section, he put createGroupList(). Looks like this was a function he commented out. What is this doing exactly? Should I be using a function like he commented out? Sorry I'm kinda new at this, I really appreciate the help

Comment: I think I actually figured that out. Two more issues tho, I want the parent group to be lists, but  dont want the child group to be sublists, I want them to be a text box I can add text to (which I grab from the net). How do i make the children textboxes rather than lists. Also, these lists show up really tiny, anyway to make them bigger? Thanks!

Comment: Added more to my answer regarding your questions in  your comments. Don't forget to +1 and accept an answer if it was helpful.

Comment: Thanks so much! This really helped me out. I'll search elsewhere for the textbox problem as I'm not super familiar with Adapter.

Comment: No problem. Good Luck, and if you figure out an easier solution, comment about it here. I am interested in your findings.

Comment: So I figure I could just edit the text that's going into the hashmap for the child class to be whatever I want. But If I do this, then every child list is the same block of text. I need to add different text depending on which parent list is opened. Any ideas?

Comment: That should not be an issue if you are creating your child list correctly. Each child will have its own `TextView`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The text getting entered in the child list comes in at this line of code: child.put( "Sub Item", "test"). I can put the text I want where it says "test" but "test" comes up under every parent list. I asked this question here too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11458214/how-to-add-different-child-lists-for-different-parents-lists-in-expandablelistvi

Comment: Added it to my post. In my additional follow up section. I also answered it in your other post.